# My mysql statement to query by primary key sometimes returns more than one row, so what happened?

Tags: mysql

My schema is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `account_type` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

INSERT INTO user VALUES (1, "zhangsan", "premiumv"), (2, "lisi", "premiumv"), (3, "wangwu", "p"), (4, "maliu", "p"), (5, "hengqi", "p"), (6, "shuba", "p");
```

I have the following 6 rows in the table:

```
+----+-----------+--------------+
| id | user_name | account_type |
+----+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | zhangsan  | premiumv     |
|  2 | lisi      | premiumv     |
|  3 | wangwu    | p            |
|  4 | maliu     | p            |
|  5 | hengqi    | p            |
|  6 | shuba     | p            |
+----+-----------+--------------+
```

Here is mysql to query the table by id:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = floor(rand()*6) + 1;
```

I expect it to return one row, but the actual result is non-predictive. It either will return 0 row, 1 row or sometimes more than one row.  Can somebody help clarify this? Thanks!

Comment: I see the same multiple rows being selected using MariaDB 10.1. The easy solution is to add `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query, but I'm very curious to see the reason for this happening.

Answer (score 2):

You're testing each row against a different random number, so sometimes multiple rows will match. To fix this, calculate the random number once in a subquery.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user AS u
JOIN (SELECT floor(rand()*6) + 1 AS r) AS r 
ON u.id = r.r
```

This method of selecting a random row from a table seems like a poor design. If there are any gaps in the `id` sequence (which can happen easily -- MySQL doesn't guarantee that they'll always be sequential, and deleting rows will leave gaps) then it could return an empty result. The usual way to select a random row from a table is with:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` part must be evaluated for each row to see if there is a match.  Because of this, the rand() function is evaluated for every row.  Getting an inconsistent number of rows seems reasonable.

If you add `LIMIT 1` to your query, the probability of returning rows from the end diminishes.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `WHERE` clause `floor(rand()*6) + 1` is evaluated against every rows in the table to see if the condition matches the criteria. The value could be different each time it is matched against the row from the table.

You can test with a table that has same values in the column used in `WHERE` clause, and you can see the result:

```
select * from test;
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | a    |
|    2 | b    |
|    1 | c    |
|    2 | d    |
|    1 | e    |
|    2 | f    |
+------+------+

select * from test where id = floor(rand()*2) + 1;
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | a    |
|    2 | d    |
|    1 | e    |
+------+------+
```

In the above example, the expression `floor(rand()*2) + 1` returns 1 when matching against the first row (with `name = 'a'`) so it is included in the result set. But then it returns 2 when matching against the forth row (with `name = 'd'`), so it is also included in the result set even the value of `id` is different from the value of the first row in the result set.